# Use array strings to choose between JSON data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

As an example, lets say I have this array:

```
var tableID = ['id','name','address'];
```

I also have a returned JSON array, which has the same strings for each column from the database. The JSON data is stored in the variable 'Results'

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Bob","address":"42 Bobs Street"}]
```

How can I use the following example, to obtain the data. Lets say I want to get Bob's Address, by using the address string in the tableID array. The way I thought to do it was (where i and j are integers from a for loop):

```
Results[i].tableID[j]
```

However this doesn't work, does anyone have a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's step through the code you tried, and see why it failed to do what you expected.

What the code you tried is actually doing is as follows:

1. Get the *ith* entry from `Results` array: `Results[i]`
2. Get the property `tableID`. `Results[i].tableID`
3. Get the *jth* entry from array stored in the `tableID` property. `Results[i].tableID[j]`

There is no `tableID` property, however. Since there is no `tableID` property, there can't be an array stored in the `tableID` property.

What you want to do instead is as follows:

1. Get the *ith* entry from `Results` array. `Results[i]`
2. Get the property with the name referred to in the *jth* index of the `tableID` array. `Results[i][tableID[j]]`

So, you could do that as follows:

```
Results[i][tableID[j]];
```

Or, if that is confusing to read (*it is to me*), you could do something like:

```
var property = tableID[j]; //Get the property first.
Results[i][property]; //Get the property from the ith record.
```

---

If you're still having trouble understanding why you need to access it this way, ask yourself what is `Results[i]` returning?

It's returning an object in an array at the *ith* position:

```
{"id":"1","name":"Bob","address":"42 Bobs Street"}
```

If this object, were assigned to a variable:

```
var obj = {"id":"1","name":"Bob","address":"42 Bobs Street"};
```

You'd access Bob's address by doing:

```
obj['address'];
```

So, combining this information, we arrive at:

```
Results[i]['address'];
```

Replace `'address'` with `tableID[j]` in the statement above, and you get:

```
Results[i][tableID[j]];
```

Comment: Thank you so much, absolute brilliant explanation. I had no idea that you could treat it as though it were a 2-dimensional array.